# Insert space between arguments to concat function

Tags: mysql

When I `concat($name, $surname)`, is there a way of putting a space in between the `$name $surname` using my sql not php so when i get the result it formats a little cleaner?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can concatenate string literals along with your fields, so you can add a space character in a string between the fields you're concatenating.

Use this:

```
 CONCAT(name, " ", surname)
```

This functionality is documented quite clearly on the [MySQL manual page for the `CONCAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

There is also the [`CONCAT_WS` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) which allows you to specify a separator to be used between each of the other fields passed to the function. If you're concatenating more than two fields in the same way, this function might be considered cleaner than repeating the separator between each field.

For example, if you wanted to add a middle name field, you could use this function to specify the separator only once:

```
CONCAT_WS(" ", first_name, middle_name, surname)
```

Answer (score 18):

Just add a space in there.

```
SELECT CONCAT(name,' ',surname) AS full_name FROM table;
```

**EDIT** oops, bad spelling there... ;p

Comment: @OMGPonies: I'm going with luck on this one. ;-)

Comment: +1. Just to be safe, I'd expand this to: `CONCAT(COALESCE(name,''),' ',COALESCE(surname,''))`

Answer (score 5):

Use this, no version dependencies

```
concat(name,Char(32),venue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT(name, ' ', surname)`.

Answer (score 0):

after trying this i tried  to do  this

```
 concat(name, _utf8 '  ' ,name1)
```

Comment: Does this answer the question ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey i had the same problem and this is what i used and it really worked out great

CONCAT(column1," ",column2)
the issue is you add physical space in between the double courts("") using the space bar on your keyboard and then thats it

Comment: What's different about this compared to the answers from a few years ago?

Answer (score 0):

**The above all options are not working ..**

*My query is*

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ' , LASTNAME) AS FULLNAME FROM USERS;
```

*getting the below error:*

`ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments 00909 00000- "invalid number of arguments" *Cause: *Action: Error at line 26 column :9`

Comment: Try `CONCAT(CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' '), LASTNAME)`, it can probably only handle two arguments at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this methoid to add separator

**EXAMPLE 01**

```
CONCAT_WS(' ', first_string, second_string, n_string, ..., last_string)
```

Output:

```
"first_string second_string n_string ... last_string"
```

**EXAMPLE 02**

```
CONCAT_WS('-', first_string, second_string, n_string, ..., last_string)
```

Output:

```
"first_string-second_string-n_string-...-last_string"
```