# How to concat multiple columns in sql

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT  EMP_HOUSE_NO,EMP_STREET_NAME,EMP_AREA,EMP_PIN_CODE

 FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS

 WHERE EMP_ID=1;
```

I need to concat these columns as address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql concat function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494775/mysql-concat-function)

Comment: Check this:
[concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427764/concatenate-two-database-columns-into-one-resultset-column)

Comment: You should edit the question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> SELECT CONCAT(EMP_HOUSE_NO,' ', EMP_STREET_NAME,' ', EMP_AREA) AS
>   address
>
> from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
>
> **WHERE** EMP_ID=1;

Answer (score 1):

Try This `select concat (EMP_HOUSE_NO,' ',EMP_STREET_NAME,' ',EMP_AREA,' ',EMP_PIN_CODE) as address from EMPLOYEE_DETAILS WHERE EMP_ID=1;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want spaces between the components, I would suggest `concat_ws()`:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', EMP_HOUSE_NO, EMP_STREET_NAME, EMP_AREA, EMP_PIN_CODE)
FROM EMPLOYEE_DETAILS
WHERE EMP_ID = 1;
```